# How to autowire when more than one beans present for dependeny classes?

Tags: java, spring, junit4, spring-test

ClassA

```
class ClassA {
    @Autowired 
    class ClassB;

    }
```

Class Config:

```
    @Configuration
    class TestConfig {
        @Bean(name = "instance1")
        public ClassB instance1() {
            return new ClassB();
        }

        @Bean(name = "instance2")
        public ClassB instance2() {
            return new ClassB();
        }
}
```

Class Test:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
    class Test {
        @Autowired
        ClassA obj1; // how to initialise it with instance1

        @Autowired
        ClassA obj2; //// how to initialise it with instance2
    }
```

How to instatiate obj1 with instance1 and obj2 with instance2 in Test class ?

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
 class Test {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("instance1")
    ClassB obj1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("instance2")
    ClassB obj2; // You can also rename obj2 as instance2 and remove @Qualifier
}
```

Create instance of ClassA using new and use constructor injection in ClassA instead of field injection(@Autowired)

```
class ClassA {
  ClassB classB;

    @Autowired 
    public ClassA(ClassB classB){
     this.classB = classB;
    }
}
```

If you cannot change your Class A, then create two TestConfig classes. Once with obj1 and once with obj2. And use accordingly based on your test case

Comment: instance1 and instance2 are of type ClassB not classA. See the very first class in the question.

Comment: ClassA has neither any parameterised constructor nor any setter for ClassB.

Comment: I can't change ClassA or classB, only Test and TestConfig can be changed.

Comment: Just create two TestConfig classes. Once with obj1 and once with obj2. And use accordingly based on your test case. There is no other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

*Note* : I do not know if I understand what you would like to do but this is my solution...

ClassA is not actually a class, but interface

```
 public interface ClassA {

        public String getInstanceName();

        public void setInstanceName(String instanceName);
    }
```

ClassB is an implementation of "ClassA" interface

```
public class ClassB implements ClassA {

    private String instanceName;

    public ClassB(String instanceName) {
        super();
        this.instanceName = instanceName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getInstanceName() {
        return instanceName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInstanceName(String instanceName) {
        this.instanceName = instanceName;
    }

}
```

The TestConfig configuration class

```
@Configuration
class TestConfig {

    @Bean(name = "instance1")
    public ClassB instance1() {
        return new ClassB("instance1");
    }

    @Bean(name = "instance2")
    public ClassB instance2() {
        return new ClassB("instance2");
    }
}
```

And the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("instance1")
    ClassA objB1; 

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("instance2")
    ClassA objB2; 

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(objB1.getInstanceName());
        System.out.println(objB2.getInstanceName());
    }

}
```

If it is not what you are looking for, maybe will help someone. About `@Autowired` annotation the doc says the following

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be
>   autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

but not a class... 
Documentation : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: instance1 and instance2 are of type ClassB not classA. See the very first class in the question.